# Sub categories in Wordpress admin panel

Tags: wordpress

I can't see sub categories in categories list

I imported in wordpress posts, comments and categories, from another wordpress installation. To do that, I imported the following tables:

- wp_posts
- wp_terms
- wp_terms_relationships
- wp_terms_taxonomy

The posts was all right, with their categories, but, if I go in wp-admin, in categories list (wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category), I see the correct number of categories, but onlu main categories. If I insert a sub category, in this case, I can see it. I forgot to import any table? What did I wrong?

-

Answer (score 0):

You forgot:

- wp_postmeta
- wp_termmeta

If you import these it *should* work, you could get some problems as the the others are already imported, though.

If it still doesn't work tell us how you transfered the tables!

Comment: I imported these too (I forgot to mention it). To import the tables I did it in the following way:

- I truncated the tables of the destination database
- I exported the tables data form the starting database
- I Imported the data in the new database.